# ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 181827

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto vue js con quasar y estoy consumiendo una api que trae el listado de muchos alumnos, el problema que tengo es que cuando la api trae demasiados registros, axios no es capaz de recibir ese arreglo de objeto, mas bien lo trae como si fuese un string gigante. Esta es la función con la que llamo a la api con axios:

```
export const LISTADO_API = ({COD_ESCUELA, ANO, PERIODO}) => {

    const url = `${rutaApi}/archivof/listado/cod_escuela/${COD_ESCUELA}?ano=${ANO}&periodo=${PERIODO}`
    return axios.get(url, {
        responseType: "json", 
        transitional: {
          silentJSONParsing: true
        }}).then((response) => {
        console.log("RESPUESTA CARGA", response)
        return response
    }).catch((error) => {
        return error
    })
}
```

y esta es la función con la que hago la carga de la tabla:

```
cargarTabla(){
            this.$q.loading.show()
 
            let obj = {
                COD_ESCUELA: this.datosUsuario.carreras[0].esc_codigo,
                ANO: this.datosUsuario.anho,
                PERIODO: this.datosUsuario.periodo
            }

        this.$store.dispatch("archivof/LISTADO_ACTION", obj).then((res) =>{
          if(this.exceptionControl(res)){
              console.log("TIPE OF",this.LISTADO_GETTER)         
                //  this.LISTADO_GETTER =  JSON.parse
            if(this.LISTADO_GETTER != null){
                this.LISTADO_GETTER.carreras.forEach(e=>{           
                    e.alumnos.forEach(a=>{
                        a.carrera_nombre = e.carrera_nombre
                    })
                    this.proptabla.items = this.proptabla.items.concat(e.alumnos)
              })  
            }  
              this.$q.loading.hide()
              console.log("DATOS CARGADOS ",this.proptabla.items)         
        }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error("ERROR: ", err)
        })

    },
```

no sé como resolver este error, al hacer un JSON.PARSE me indica que es la posición 181827 la que genera el error, al hacer una búsqueda encontré que esa posición se compone de esto:

"secciÃ³n que se acomoda mejor a mi horario. SecciÃ³n W    MARTES 09:40-10:40 16/08/2021_24/12/2021JUEVES 17:50-18:50 16/08/2021_24/12/2021    JORQUERA ROJAS OSCAR ENRIQUE"

Comment: Alguien propuso una edición queriendo eliminar la imagen debido a que contiene datos completos. Ten cuidado, esto es internet, si publicaste datos importantes en esta pregunta, todos los pueden ver. Incluso aquellos que quieran usar esos datos con malas intenciones.